# Can we have an extension function for suspend function?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

if i use :

```
suspend fun <T> A(block: suspend () -> T){
///std.
}
```

all things go right but :

```
suspend fun <T> (suspend () -> T).A(){
///std.
}.
```

no compilation errors , but i cant use it with suspend functions.

for example that we have this fun (do work is a suspend function):

```
accountManager.doWork(password)
```

in case #1 its works fine:

```
A {
accountManager.doWork(password)
}
```

in case #2 it does not work as expected(compilation error):

```
accountManager.doWork(password).A()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "i cant use it with suspend functions"? How do you want to use it?

Comment: `(::delay).A()`

Comment: `accountManager.doWork(password).A()` calls `A` on the return value of `doWork`. It does not call `A` on the function `doWork` itself. Maybe you meant `suspend { accountManager.doWork(password) }.A()`? Not sure why you would prefer that over `A { accountManager.doWork(password) }` though.

Comment: thx ... yup its works ... but with your view every function should return a suspend . and in my case doWork is a response from database.
.......
for what i need >>> i need this to do try catch around this block and return the on success and on error .@Sweeper

Comment: @Mohmmaed-Amleh That sounds like something you should do in `A`? I fail to see what the problem is...

Comment: @Sweeper exactly i need to surround doWork with try catch and return onSucces & onError

Comment: suspend fun <T> successOrError(block: suspend () -> T, onError: (Throwable) -> Unit) {
    try {
        block.invoke()
    } catch (cause: Throwable) {
        if (cause is CancellationException)
            throw cause

        onError(cause)
    }
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The receiver of

```
accountManager.doWork(password).A()
```

is whatever `doWork(password)` returns, *not* the `doWork` function itself. Let's suppose that `doWork` returns `String`, then the above would have worked if `A` were an extension function on `String`:

```
// Depending on what you do in its implementation, 
// A does not need to be a suspending function
fun String.A() {

}
```

---

If you want `A`'s receiver to be the function `doWork` instead, the syntax is:

```
(accountManager::doWork).A()
```

Then the above will compile if `A` is declared like this:

```
suspend fun <T, R> (suspend (T) -> R).A() {

}
```

Notice that the receiver type is a function that takes *one* parameter, since `doWork` takes one parameter.

---

If what you actually want to do is to use the entire suspending lambda you passed to `A` as a parameter here...

```
A {
    accountManager.doWork(password)
}
```

...as the *receiver* of the new extension function `A` that you are declaring, then your attempt is correct:

```
suspend fun <T> (suspend () -> T).A(){

}
```

You should call it on a suspending lambda:

```
suspend { accountManager.doWork(password) }.A()
```

Though I'm not sure why you would prefer this to the way more readable `A { ... }` syntax.